# Generate metadata for cloud images

Tags: post-meta, uploads, thumbnails, amazon, cloud

#### The current situation

We use the [**AWS SDK for PHP**](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) to store media files on S3 instead of the server's local storage, and use the `wp_handle_upload` filter to point the inserted attachment to the S3 file URL instead of the local file path and delete the local file as well.

```php
function upload_to_s3( $upload ) {
    // MyS3Client, is a custom class that creates an S3Client object.
    $s3client = new MyS3Client();
    // myUploadMethod, is a custom method that stores the file on S3 and return its path.
    $s3_path  = $s3client->myUploadMethod( $upload );
    // Delete the local file.
    unlink( $upload['file'] );
    // Alter the file URL to point to S3.
    $upload['url']  = $s3_path;
    $upload['file'] = $s3_path;
    return $upload;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'upload_to_s3' );
```

Something else, we don't generate any resized thumbnails from the original uploaded images; because we utilize the [**AWS Serverless Image Handler**](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler) library to generate the needed sizes on the fly and serve them via CDN.

```php
// Disable generating any resized thumbnails for the uploaded image.
add_action( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', '__return_empty_array' );
```

So we insert these thumbnail sizes into DB manually; because WordPress uses some of them in the backend, like the images' thumbnails in the Media Library page, or the Media uploader form. At this point, we use the on-the-fly URL that will generate the thumbnails and store them on CDN.

```php
function generate_cdn_thumbnails( $metadata, $attachment_id, $context ) {
    if ( $context === 'create') {
        $attachment_path   = parse_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) )['path'];
        $metadata['sizes'] = [
            'thumbnail' => [
                'file'      => 'https://cdn.example.com/fit-in/150x150' . $attachment_path,
                'width'     => 150,
                'height'    => 150,
                'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
            ],
            'medium'    => [
                'file'      => 'https://cdn.example.com/fit-in/300x300' . $attachment_path,
                'width'     => 300,
                'height'    => 300,
                'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
            ],
            'large'     => [
                'file'      => 'https://cdn.example.com/fit-in/1024x1024' . $attachment_path,
                'width'     => 1024,
                'height'    => 1024,
                'mime-type' => 'image/jpeg',
            ],
        ];
    }
    return $metadata;
}
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'generate_cdn_thumbnails', 10, 3 );
```

#### The problems

##### 1. Generate the metadata of the image before `unlink` it.

We know that WordPress can generate the metadata (`width`, `height`, `filesize`, `image_meta`, ...) of the local images only. So, either to generate them before `unlink` the local file, or download the uploaded image from S3 to the server to generate these data.

Currently we `unlink` the local file in the `wp_handle_upload` hook, so the file will be deleted before generating the metadata in the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` hook.

Is there any better hook to use so we can `unlink` the file after generating its metadata? And how to pass the full local path of the file to that hook to use it in the `unlink` function?

##### 2. Filter the resized CDN thumbnails URLs

In the `generate_cdn_thumbnails` function above, we store the full CDN URL of the thumbnails that will be generated on the fly. But when displaying these thumbnails in the backend (Media Library page, for example), WordPress prepends the folder path of the original image to that full URL.

Suppose we have this URL of the `thumbnail` size image:

```
https://cdn.example.com/fit-in/150x150/2022/07/18/my_image.jpg
```

The original (unlinked) image folder path `https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/18/` will be prepended to the thumbnail's full CDN URL, so the thumbnail will have this final URL (which is a broken URL) when displaying it on the Media page:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/18/https://cdn.example.com/fit-in/150x150/2022/07/18/my_image.jpg
```

What is the proper hook to use to filter and fix the thumbnail URL before displaying it on the Media page?

Comment: Are you aware of [Tachyon](https://github.com/humanmade/tachyon) and [S3 Uploads](https://github.com/humanmade/s3-uploads)? Those have already solved these problems and may hold a solution for you (assuming you can't just use them as is). Also you should only ask 1 question per question. This isn't a discussion forum, so to write an answer you would need to answer both questions and be correct in answering both at the same time, so people are much less likely to answer. Whereas 2 questions asked separately is much easier and gets more views

Comment: can you explain why do you want to delete local files in the first place?

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell, we had used the **S3 Uploads** before, but we are trying to use the AWS SDK directly without the mean on any other plugins. For the **Tachyon**, it's the first time to hear about it, and it seems interesting, but we do other stuff besides the resizing, like the watermarking and image type conversion to `webp`. I think we may of with these plugins if we didn't get a solution.
And for the 2 questions, I know you are right, but both are related to each other and have almost the same core reason.
Appreciate your understanding and your kind reply! Thank you!

Comment: @MarkKaplun, since we send the file to Amazon S3, we need to free up the server storage. We are a news channel website and our Media assets exceed 50TB, so we can't keep all of that on the local storage of the server.
And we have multiple servers that run our website and are linked with a load balancer to distribute the traffic, so the file will be available on one of the servers only, while on S3, it will be accessible for all the servers.

Comment: @JafarAbazeed that is good reason... have you tried to find S3 NFS adopter to use S3 as an external drive https://serverfault.com/questions/940827/how-can-you-use-amazon-s3-or-s3-compatible-storage-as-nfs.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, sounds like a good solution, we can map the `/uploads` folder as a shared drive between all the servers. But still the second question, what's the proper hook to use to alter the thumbnail image URL so we can remove the prepended folder path. Do you have an idea @MarkKaplun, @TomJNowell?

Comment: @JafarAbazeed If you just need to manipulate the thumbnail url then changing the DB is just too much, a better approch can be to filter the html generated when you call the relevant image/attachments API, there you can handle things differently if you are in admin or front-end context

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the metadata portion of your question...I wonder if you could use the exif_read_data function?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php